# Fabricjs 2.0 How to set underline to substring of the Textbox

Tags: fabricjs, fabricjs2

I have Textbox with text "This is test textbox", i want to set underline to only word "test" not the whole textbox text. How do i set underline to the substring?

[fabricjs issue](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/4870)

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var underlineText = new fabric.Textbox("This is test textbox", {
  underline: true,
});

canvas.add(underlineText);
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="1000" height="500"></canvas>
```

As 2.0 is not ready yet for docs and examples, one thing that changed is that textDecoration has been removed.
In place we have: `.underline, .overline, .linetrought` each of them with a true or false. issue

Thanks. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disagree that 2.0 is not ready for docs and examples.
Docs and examples from 1.0 have been converted and some more added.

Said so, that i know nothing has to do with the question, all Text classes in fabricJS have a `setSelectionStyle` method that take a style object and a start and end index as argume nts.

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Text.html#setSelectionStyles

So calling:

`myText.setSelectionStyles({ underline: true }, 2, 4);`

Should set underline to the text char in position 2, 3 and 4.